# Durandal routing issue

Tags: router, durandal

I have small SPA test app with Durandal.
Also I have very wired issue.
First, my folder structure is:
App
--durandal
--viewmodels
----user.js
--views
----user.html 
--main.js
And when structure is like that all works just fine. But if I create structure like 
App 
--durandal 
--_user 
----viewmodels
------user.js
----views
------user.html

I get error like localhost/App/_users/**viewmodels**/users.html 404 Not Found. And that happens after user.js are loaded by require.js.

my main.js looks like

```
require.config({
   paths: { "text": "../durandal/amd/text" }
});

define(function (require) {
   var system = require('../durandal/system'),
      app = require('../durandal/app'),
      router = require('../durandal/plugins/router'),
      viewLocator = require('../durandal/viewLocator'),
      logger = require('../logger');

   system.debug(true);

   app.start().then(function () {
      // route will use conventions for modules
      // assuming viewmodels/views folder structure
      router.useConvention();


      // When finding a module, replace the viewmodel string 
      // with view to find it partner view.
      // [viewmodel]s/sessions --> [view]s/sessions.html
      // Otherwise you can pass paths for modules, views, partials
      // Defaults to viewmodels/views/views. 
      viewLocator.useConvention();

      app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell');

      // override bad route behavior to write to 
      // console log and show error toast
      router.handleInvalidRoute = function (route, params) {
         logger.logError('No route found', route, 'main', true);
      };
   });
});
```

I assume that this issue has something with router.useConvention(); or with viewLocator.useConvention(); but simple can't find any reason for that kind of behavior.

Any help, suggestion, idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is because of the behavior of the [view locator](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/View-Locator/), which by defaults looks for views/viewmodels in the first structure you describe.

You can easily change this behavior by supplying your own view locator function, or by calling `useConvention()` like this `useConvention(modulesPath, viewsPath, areasPath)`

Comment: Thanks, but that useConvention() or doesn't work or I just don't know what exactly to put there. If I put there something like  useConvention('_users/viewmodels', '_users/views')  then app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell'); doesn't works and then I get error 404 Not Found - localhost/App/_users/viewmodels/shell.html".
If I put just .useConvention('viewmodels', 'views');, then again get localhost/App/_users/viewmodels/users.html 404 Not Found. So, this is very confusing and if I move my user.html from views folder to viewfolder then all forks. But get slightly different debug messages.

Comment: Use `useConvention('_users/viewmodels', '_users/views', '_users/views')` and `app.setRoot('_users/viewmodels/shell')`. That should work. Remember, any time you reference a viewmodel you must still use the *full* moduleid path, which is the path from the App folder.

Comment: Thanks, but that still does not working. When I apply your suggestion then I get "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - localhost/App/_users/_users/viewmodels/shell.js"

Comment: I just noticed in your first comment that the 404 was looking for `viewmodels/shell.html` which is obviously not going to be there, it should be looking for the html in `views`. Are you sure you didn't switch the parameters the first time? Can you try `useConvention('_users/viewmodels', '_users/views', '_users/views') then app.setRoot('viewmodels/shell')` again?